# Why no Magnetizing inductance on the secondary side of the transfomer model?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Here is the electrical model of a transformer : 
[image]

Why there is no magnetizing inductance in the secondary side ? Actually the model is true if we want always passing current from the primary side to the secondary side ? Is this the answer ?

Just for information the resistance next to the magnetizing inductance represents the core loss (eddy current and ???) ? So it is the part of the current whose the "energy" cannot be transfered to the secondary ?

Thank you very much !